# Spacing in between banned words - Regular Expression Python

Tags: python, regex

I am currently attempting to make a form of censor which will remove specific words. I am currently dealing with the idea that a user will be able to add spaces in between their letters and bypass the censor.

An example:

```
Banned word: Apple
Solution: A p p l e
```

Is there a way to combat this within Regex? My immediate thought is to use something akin to:

```
(a\s*p\s*p\s*l\s*e\s*)
```

However I feel like this is not an optimal solution.

If there is a solution to this, please do let me know. Thank you.

Edit:

Apples is not actually a banned word, just a placeholder for more crude words.

The idea of taking away white space and then comparing is not available, as some harmless words can be flagged this way. As an example:

```
"We need a medic, he's hit --> weneedamediche'[shit]" FLAGGED.
```

Comment: one approach is to remove whitespace between single characters, and then comparing your banned words

Comment: You can remove all spaces and find banned word in spaces-removed string.

Comment: Is it always a word or can it be a sentence?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it easier to understand the problem and solutions

Comment: If someone wanted to, they'll always find away around your censorship. The solution is really to strengthen how you handle offences

Comment: This should be fun.  There's a classic story a friend tells of attempting to perform some censorship by replacing "more offensive" words with "less offensive" versions while employed by a big telco, and they realized their algorithm wasn't quite right when people began talking about the recent buttbuttination attempt.

My main point here is that any algorithm which is aggressive enough to detect your test cases probably also has a high false positive rate, and any algorithm which has a low false positive rate is probably easily defeated.  This is a losing battle.  Pick a different one.

Comment: What happens with A-p-p-l-e?  A.p.p.l.e?   It’s not a very realistic requirement, at least using regexes, good luck telling stakeholders. Better bet’s on aggressive penalties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will be helpful.

```
sentence = 'learn to play with code'
sentence_to_word_list = sentence.split(' ') # spliting sentence to words here
banned_Words = ['to', 'with']   # list of banned words

for index, word in enumerate(sentence_to_word_list): # enumerate is used to track the index of each word
    if word in banned_Words:
        sentence_to_word_list[index] = '-'.join(list(word)) # we can join word here with any character,symbol or number

sentence = ' '.join(sentence_to_word_list) # again joining the list of word to make the whole sentence
print(sentence) # output : learn t-o play w-i-t-h code
```

Answer (score 1):

If your entry is a word with spaces, your regex works fine, however the `strip` method allows you to keep a record of the bad words and compare to them without generating regex for each bad word.

```py
s = "A p p l e"
s = s.trim() 
print(is_badword(s))
```

If your entry is a text and your parsing it looking for bad words, then it becomes more difficult since I suppose you already rely on white spaces to get your tokens.

You would have to test every possible combinations of successive tokens. That is not achievable with a regex, but it should be manageable with a search tree for bad words in `O(t^2)` where `t` is the number of tokens.
(Also I suppose users could also break the bad words other way than on each character, like `Ap p le`)